# $q:X\rightarrow C$ has the same homotopy type of $M_f\rightarrow X \rightarrow C_f$, what does this mean?

Tags: homotopy-theory

The book I'm reading says that a sequence $A \rightarrow X \rightarrow C$ (with maps $f$ and $q$ respectively) is a **cofibre sequence** if $q:X\rightarrow C$ has the homotopy type of $M_f\rightarrow X\rightarrow C_f$, in which $M_f$ and $C_f$ are the mapping cylinder and cone, and $M_f\rightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence. I don't understand what it means to say that those two have the same homotopy type (since he is not talking about spaces apparently, but about the maps)

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Comment: I am reading "Lusternik-Schnirelmann Category" by Octav Cornea, Gregory Lupton, John Oprea and Daniel Tanré. The precise part I am talking about is in "Appendix B: Basic Homotopy", page 296, before Example B.6.

Comment: Have a look at Jeff Strom's book *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory* $\S$ 4.7, pg. 91. Although I think there are much more intuitive definitions for cofibre sequences. If you want to learn homotopy theory, Strom's book is a pretty decent place to start, rather than trying to figure stuff out from apendices (although I do love your book).